# Isomorphisms mod nonstationary

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

Suppose $G \subseteq \mathrm{Add}(\omega_1)$ is generic over $V$.  Let $X_i = \{ \alpha : G(\alpha) = i \}$.  Is it true that $P(X_0)/\mathrm{NS} \cong P(X_1)/\mathrm{NS}$?